# Visual Studio 2010 check-in to TFS results in 0x8000FFFF error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, checkin

Sometimes when I try to do check-in to TFS, I get the following message:

[image: 0x8000FFFF error message]

And the check-in fails.

Searching the Internet for this, it seems to be E_UNEXPECTED, or if it uses COM it also could mean "Catastrophic failure".

But I predictably found no solution for this, as the error message is doing very poorly its job of giving information on what is happening.

How can I make this will not happen again?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this error by upgrading to a newer version of visual studio and TFS. TFS and Visual Studio 2010 fall out of mainstream support in a couple of months. You need to start your upgrade planning now!

http://nakedalm.com/blog/its-that-time-again-get-ready-to-upgrade-to-tfs-2015/

Due to you still being on 2010 after all this time, I would recommend moving to Visual Studio Online rather than trying to run TFS internally.